# Extract text from a text file and write in a different format

Tags: python, parsing, text

Hi I'm trying to extract some lines of text from a file generated from a program and write to another text file in a different format using python.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import os
import glob



path="D:\Programming\Python\Examples\Home\GainWizard\MassLynx\VxWorks\TargetRegistryFiles"
os.chdir(path)
print os.getcwd()
print os.listdir(path)


filelist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
filelist = filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), filelist)
newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)

print newest
f = open(newest,'r')

data = f.readlines()
print data
```

This adds all the text to a list

What I have is

```
Autotune Ion Energy:Fixed Ion Energy 1,2.000000,Autotune Ion Energy:Fixed Ion Energy      2,2.000000,Autotune Ion Energy:MS1-Neg Opt,0.3,Autotune Ion Energy:MS1-Pos Opt,-0.2,Autotune Ion Energy:MS2-Neg Opt,0.4,Autotune Ion Energy:MS2-Pos Opt,0.6,Autotune Ion Energy:MSMS Mode Fixed Ion Energy 1,0.500000,Autotune Ion Energy:MSMS Mode Fixed Ion Energy 2,2.000000,Autotune Ion Energy:OptimumValuesSet,true,Debug:Use old bunching method,true,Detector Gain Negative:High Gain,368.861012,Detector Gain Negative:Low Gain,73.523644,Detector Gain Negative:a,1.865677e-021,Detector Gain Negative:b,8.441605,Detector Gain Postitve:High Gain,613.662847,Detector Gain Postitve:Low Gain,124.065398,Detector Gain Postitve:a,4.973557e-021,Detector Gain Postitve:b,8.367407,DivertValve:ValveZone,0,Engineers Settings:MS1 DC Balance -,0.300000,Engineers Settings:MS1 DC Polarity,1,Engineers Settings:MS1 High Mass Position,174.000000,Engineers Settings:MS1 High Mass Resolution,1801.000000,Engineers Settings:MS1 Low Mass Position,519.000000,Engineers Settings:MS1 Low Mass Resolution,511.000000,Engineers Settings:MS1 Resolution Linearity,873.000000,Engineers Settings:MS2 DC Balance -,-0.200000,Engineers Settings:MS2 DC Polarity,0,Engineers Settings:MS2 High Mass Position,190.000000,Engineers Settings:MS2 High Mass Resolution,1744.000000,Engineers Settings:MS2 Low Mass Position,519.000000,Engineers Settings:MS2 Low Mass Resolution,514.000000,Engineers Settings:MS2 Resolution Linearity,857.000000,Engineers Settings:PIC MS Scan CE,4.000000,Engineers Settings:PIC Threshold Calc Scan Delay,3,Engineers Settings:PIC decreasing data points,3,Engineers Settings:PIC nonDefault Scan Speed,5000.000000,Engineers Settings:PMT Type,Hamamatsu,Engineers Settings:RF Offset Negative,0.000000,Engineers Settings:RF Offset Positive,0.000000,Failure:Gas failed state,OK,Failure:Leak detected state,Tripped,Fluidics:AcknowledgeCountThreshold,5,Fluidics:ActiveReservoir,2,Fluidics:Aspirate Rate,1000,Fluidics:Draw Rate,1000,Fluidics:Fill Volume,250,Fluidics:Flow Rate,10,Fluidics:Flow State,Waste,Fluidics:Inject-Flow Rate,400,Fluidics:Inject-MethodType,4,Fluidics:Inject-Pump Time1,5,Fluidics:Inject-Pump Time2,6,Fluidics:Inject-Pump Time3,10,Fluidics:Max Flow Rate,1500,Fluidics:Pending Active TimeOut,10,Fluidics:Pending Complete TimeOut,1200,Fluidics:Pending Response TimeOut,10,Fluidics:Power Cycle Delay,3.000000,Fluidics:Precompression Dispense Rate,300,Fluidics:Precompression Dispense Volume,30,Fluidics:Precompression Enable,TRUE,Fluidics:Precompression Max Fill Volume,280,Fluidics:Purge Delay Length,1,Fluidics:Refill Wait Time,60.000000,Fluidics:Sample Purge Count,0,Fluidics:Wash Purge Count,1,Instrument:Collision gas status,off,Instrument:EPC Version,Feb 15 2012,Instrument:Serial Number,QCA331,Instrument:Unique Name,,Ion Energy Settings:Fixed Ion Energy 1,3.000000,Ion Energy Settings:Fixed Ion Energy 2,3.000000,Maintenance Counters:DAYS_SINCE_LAST_SERVICE_THRESHOLD,0,Maintenance Counters:OPERATE_SWITCHES,28,Maintenance Counters:OPERATE_SWITCHES_THRESHOLD,0,Maintenance Counters:OPERATE_TIME,141233,Maintenance Counters:OPERATE_TIME_THRESHOLD,0,Maintenance Counters:POLARITY_SWITCHES,187,Maintenance Counters:POLARITY_SWITCHES_THRESHOLD,0,Maintenance Counters:VACUUM_TIME,763973,Maintenance Counters:VACUUM_TIME_THRESHOLD,0,Protective Actions:ENABLE_DIVERT_TO_WASTE,1,Scan Parameters:Interchannel Delay,0.020000,Scan Parameters:Interscan Delay,0.020000,Scan Parameters:Manual Mode,true,Scan Parameters:Polarity Switching Interscan Delay,0.020000,Scan Parameters:Scan Speed Options,1000\,2000\,5000\,10000,Scan speed adjust::DefaultsVersionLevel,2,Scan speed adjust:HIGH_SCALE_MASS_ADJUST_MS1_SETTING,-60.000000,Scan speed adjust:HIGH_SCALE_MASS_ADJUST_MS2_SETTING,-32.000000,Scan speed adjust:ION_ENERGY_1_RAMP_SETTING,2.000000,Scan speed adjust:ION_ENERGY_2_RAMP_SETTING,2.000000,Scan speed adjust:LINEARITY_ADJUST_MS1_SETTING,0.000000,Scan speed adjust:LINEARITY_ADJUST_MS2_SETTING,0.000000,Scan speed adjust:LOW_MASS_RESOLUTION_MS1_SETTING,10.000000,Scan speed adjust:LOW_MASS_RESOLUTION_MS2_SETTING,20.000000,Scan speed adjust:LOW_SCALE_MASS_ADJUST_MS1_SETTING,-15.000000,Scan speed adjust:LOW_SCALE_MASS_ADJUST_MS2_SETTING,-15.000000,Scan speed adjust:MS1_ION_ENERGY_SETTING,1.000000,Scan speed adjust:MS1_ION_ENERGY_WRITE_SETTING,1.000000,Scan speed adjust:MS2_ION_ENERGY_SETTING,0.700000,Scan speed adjust:MS2_ION_ENERGY_WRITE_SETTING,0.700000,Scan speed adjust:RESOLUTION_ADJUST_MS1_SETTING,-15.000000,Scan speed adjust:RESOLUTION_ADJUST_MS2_SETTING,0.000000
```

What I need is

```
START_TARGET_REGISTRY
Detector Gain Negative:a,1.087668e-021
Detector Gain Negative:b,8.536190
Detector Gain Negative:High Gain,392.233021 
Detector Gain Negative:Low Gain,76.782164
Detector Gain Postitve:a,4.061385e-021 
Detector Gain Postitve:b,8.398445
Detector Gain Postitve:High Gain,610.368775
Detector Gain Postitve:Low Gain,122.669833
END_TARGET_REGISTRY
```

Thanks

Comment: Just an aside - it might be more efficient (or at least more readable) to use `newest = max(filelist, key=os.path.getmtime)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not to concerned about that part of the code, will tidy up once I can figure out how to extract the info I need, I'm new to Python so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Another side note: better use the forward slash (`/`) in your paths, even on Windows. Or escape the backslashes. Or maybe use raw strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things aren't quite clear, like whether you need more parameters than just the "Detector Gain" ones or where the numbers come from (since they don't appear in your example).

However, this might get you to where you need to be:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

D = OrderedDict()
for field in data.split(','):    
    if ':' in field:
        k = field
    else:
        D[k]= field.strip()

with open(r"C:\temp\detector_gain.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    print("START_TARGET_REGISTRY", file=outfile)
    for k, v in D.items():
        if "Detector Gain" in k:
           print(k, v, sep=',', file=outfile)
    print("END_TARGET_REGISTRY", file=outfile)
```

Since the format of the data seems to be `CATEGORY_1:KEY_1,VALUE_1,CATEGORY_2:KEY_2,VALUE_2...` we break the data into fields at each comma with the [split](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Then we loop through each field, looking for a : character, which tells us that we're reading a `CATEGORY:KEY` field.

Once we have the `CATEGORY:KEY` field, we know the next field will be the associated value. So we add that to a Python dictionary, which maps keys to values. I chose the [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) dictionary in case the order of the fields is important.

At the end we read through the dictionary we constructed, looking for the "Detector Gain" fields. Then we print them to an outfile - you can see how we open it for writing with a context manager.

If you're on Python 2 also do `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: Hi Bo102010, I tried that tonight and it works perfect, can you talk me through how this works. How do I write this output to a file, thanks for your help.

Comment: I simplified the code and added some comments. If this works for you you can go ahead and accept this as the answer.